# convert loop in array_map in php

Tags: php, loops

I have the following loop in php:

```
for ($c = 0; $c < 1280; $c++) { //1280
        for ($d = 0; $d < 15; $d++) {                   
            $temp_1=-1*$theta[$d][1];   

            $temp_2=($s[$c][$d+1]-$x[$d]);

            $corrFunFict = $corrFunFict+($temp_1*$temp_2*$temp_2);

            // this original code was slower!!
            //$corrFunFict = $corrFunFict+(-1*$theta[$d][1] * pow(($s[$c][$d+1]-$x[$d]),2) );   
        }   
        $corrFun[$c] = exp($corrFunFict);       
        $corrFunFict =0;
    }
```

The matrices involved are `$theta` (2 columns, 15 rows), `$s` (16 columns, 1280 rows) and array `$x` (15 elements).

Is there a way to make this loop faster? I have simplified the formula for `$corrFunFict` (commented), but maybe using `array_map`? Another option: is there a library for matrix operations that can substitute the loop somehow?

Comment: In terms of micro-optimization you should use `++$c` and `++$d` in your `for()` loops. Also, `array_map()` will actually slow your code down since it adds the overhead of calling a function.

Comment: How slow is this code right now?

Comment: It takes 0.02 seconds. But running it 230 times makes a lot of time... and I can not change the number of times the loop is called :(

Comment: What's the slowest line in that loop? Is it the `exp()` function?

Comment: What's the point of the inner loop? Only the result of the last iteration will ever be used. Or is $corrFunFict a type?

Comment: Yes, the exp() is the slowest, it takes 0.014, the other lines 0.008 to 0.010.. I tried pow(2.718282,$corrFunFict); but it's even slower.

Comment: 230 x .02 seconds = 4.6 seconds, so I guess it depends on your definition of "a lot of time". If it's a one-off process or something that only gets run occasionally, 4.6 seconds really isn't a long time. If it's something that gets run on every page load of a busy site, then yes, it is a big issue. The best advice I can give for saving time is to cache the results -- if you're running the same calculations more than once, save the results and use the cached values next time instead of re-calculating.

Comment: Just a note, `array_*` is slower that loops, because it gives an overhead of function call. I have benchmarked that sometimes before myself, and it really is slower.